# Can I define a ListView Builder with itemCount that isn't declared initially

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

The title must've been confusing. I actually don't know how to exactly describe it. However, I'll try my best to do so with the code sample:

So, I am trying to display a list of card under an expansion tile. The items to be displayed on these cards are dynamic and differ between expansion tiles. To do so I've used the property 'onExpansionChanged'. On this property I've written the following code:

```
onExpansionChanged: (value) {
  if (rearrangedDays[index] == 'Saturday' || rearrangedDays[index] == 'Sunday') {
    hour = ratesData.firstHourWeekend;
    print(ratesData.ratesWeekend);
    rates = ratesData.ratesWeekend;
    print(rates);
  } else {
    hour = ratesData.firstHourWeekday;
    print(ratesData.ratesWeekday);
    rates = ratesData.ratesWeekday;
    print(rates);                        
  }
}
```

And under the ListView Builder inside the child property of the ExpansionTile I have:

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: rates.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text((hour++).toString() + ':00'),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Text(
                'Rs. ' + rates[index],
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily:'silka'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Now the problem is, if I just declare an array, the item count will show an error saying it returned null. If I don't declare it initially and do it inside expansion changed, the rates variable in item count gives an error saying there's no such variable declared. As a workaround I've been initializing the array to a few empty elements.

```
List<String> rates = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','','',''];
```

This way itemCount isn't null and the elements that I copy into the array in 'onExpansionChanged' is shown in the cards. This doesn't look like the right way. Plus if I were to display lesser or more elements than the number of empty elements I've initialized into the array, it gives me a range error.

I know this might be unclear. I really need this fixed so I'm ready to answer any extra details that you might need to help me debug this.

UPDATE:
I added setState to make the changes and added a conditional operator before Container. It worked but had some side effects. Now the ListView Builder keeps building infinite ExpansionTiles.

```
return ExpansionTile(
 onExpansionChanged: (value) {
  setState(() {
   rates = ratesData.ratesWeekend;
  });

  setState(() {
   rates = ratesData.ratesWeekday;
  });
 },
 children:<widget>[
  ListView.builder(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemCount: rates.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Card(
     child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
       child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
         Text((hour++).toString() + ':00'),
         SizedBox(height: 10.0),
         Text(
          'Rs. ' + rates[index],
           style: TextStyle(fontFamily:'silka'),
          ),
         ],
        ),
       ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
]
);
```

Comment: Why you not checking before `return ListView.builder` that your `rates` are null or null if null then return `Container()` otherwise `ListView.builder`

Comment: Then it would always show the Container right? Or will it dynamically update once it gets the value of rates that I set in onExpansionChanged?

Comment: Think you have a list named `rates` and now it is `null` so the view will empty `Container()` and when you got `rates` with data set in a state like `setState(){ // update rates}`  so you view will be refreashed and will show `ListView.builder`. Same case in `ExpansionTile` if you want show list in `ExpansionTile` checking the same null or empty list

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check if the `rates` array is null before setting the `itemCount` value

```
itemCount: rates == null ? 0 : rates.length,
```

this will set the `itemCount` to zero when the array returns null and hence will not display any item on the screen. This should solve your issue.

[UPDATE]
So actually just stick to your original `onExpansionChanged` function and add the `setState()` to each condition. I believe this should work.

```
onExpansionChanged: (value) {
  if (rearrangedDays[index] == 'Saturday' || rearrangedDays[index] == 'Sunday') {
    hour = ratesData.firstHourWeekend;
    print(ratesData.ratesWeekend);
    setState(() { // add your setState() this way
      rates = ratesData.ratesWeekend;
    });
    print(rates);
  } else {
    hour = ratesData.firstHourWeekday;
    print(ratesData.ratesWeekday);
    setState(() { // add your second setState() this way
      rates = ratesData.ratesWeekday;
    });
    print(rates);                        
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay that did work but it created more issues. So now whenever I tap an expansion tile to see the cards it keeps on building new expansion tiles below. So now I have 4-5 copies of the same expansion tiles.

I think the Listview builder is getting called every time a setState is run. Is there anyway to stop that while still using Expansion Tiles or should I go for something else?

Comment: Where are you calling setState()

Comment: Inside onExpansionChanged of ExpansionTile which is in a ListView

Comment: If there's any workaround to stop ListView expanding then that'd be great. Or else I can just manually add ExpansionTiles as I only need 7 of them. Or I could create a function and call it 7 times. Or if that hogs the resource too much I'll use some other simpler implementation.

Comment: @KartabyaAryal can you post code of where you have the setState() called?

Comment: I think I know what might be causing the issue. You are calling setState() twice in the update code you posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206975/discussion-between-mjhansen3-and-kartabya-aryal).